# Can't compute percentage changes using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a question regarding the use of dplyr. For variables A, B, and C in a data frame, I want to calculate the YOY changes using dplyr. Could someone tell me why I get an error ("Error: Evaluation error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.")?

PS. I really want to pass multiple arguments to dplyr "mutate" function to solve this issue. Thank you in advance!

```
set.seed(10)

dat <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10,0,1),
                  B=rnorm(10,0,1),
                  c=rnorm(10,0,1),
                  D=2001:2010)

dat %>%  
  arrange(D) %>%  
  mutate(A_pct_chg = (A-lag(A))/lag(A), 
         B_pct_chg = (B-lag(B))/lag(B), 
         C_pct_chg = (C-lag(C))/lag(C))
```

**Edit:**

Thank you so much! Also, I want to write a helper function that summarizes the percentage change for column A, B and C in one shot. I want to pass a string to the "mutate" argument of dplyr with the help of rlang. Unfortunately, I get an error saying that I have an unexpected ",". Could you please take a look, if possible?

```
library(rlang) #read text inputs and return vars
library(dplyr)


set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10,0,1),
                  B=rnorm(10,0,1),
                  C=rnorm(10,0,1),
                  D=2001:2010)

calc_perct_chg <- function(input_data,
                           target_Var_list,
                           year_Var_name){

      #create new variable names
          mutate_varNames <- paste0(target_Var_list,rep("_pct_chg = ",length(target_Var_list)))
     
      #generate text for formula
          mutate_formula  <- lapply(target_Var_list,function(x){output <- paste0("(",x,"-lag(",x,"))/lag(",x,")");return(output)})
          mutate_formula  <- unlist(mutate_formula) #convert list to a vector
   
      #generate arguments for mutate
          mutate_args <<- paste0(mutate_varNames,collapse=",",mutate_formula)
    
      #data manipulation
           output <- input_data %>% 
                         arrange(!!parse_quo(year_Var_name,env=caller_env())) %>% 
                         mutate(!!parse_quo(mutate_args,env=caller_env()))
      #output data frame
          return(output)
}

 

calc_perct_chg(input_data =dat,
               target_Var_list=list("A","B","C"),
               year_Var_name="D") #error: unexpected ','
```

Comment: Probably better to submit the revision as a new question and accept this answer if it solved the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in mutate you used upper-case C which is the name of an R function, `C()`, whereas the column name in your data frame is lower-case c.

It will work if the column name is changed to upper-case C because R will realise that column is in the data frame and not confuse it with the function.